# Pass session created outside of magento to magento site

Tags: php, magento

I am creating one app in which i want to do some part in frame work like yii2 or CI and some part in magento so i want to pass session created outside of magento to the magento app and vice versa.
I want to know is it possible to do this task and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can use magento session out side magento it's previous solved answer
you need to include mage.php in your file
like

```
require_once ('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app(); 

// Define the path to the root of Magento installation.
define('ROOT', Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB));

// Obtain the general session and search for an item called 'customer_id'
$core_session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' =>       'frontend'));
if(isset($coreSession['visitor_data']['customer_id'])){
$customerId = $coreSession['visitor_data']['customer_id'];
} else {
header('Location: '.ROOT.'customer/account/login/');
}

// Load the user session.
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customerId);
$customerSession = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

// We verified that created successfully (not required)
if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
header('Location: '.ROOT.'customer/account/login/');
}

// Load customer
$customer = $customerSession->getCustomer();

// We get cell phone
$telefono = $customer->getTelefonoMovil();
```

Comment: Hey shakir is there any link to do such things.I am beginner in magento .

Comment: did you check this solution it is working or not for you?  yes there are many examples in google. if you get result from this solution you can get anything outside of magento.

Comment: I am not getting current session so i am redirecting to login page always.

Comment: you are login with admin or frontend?

Comment: I am login with frontend.

Comment: did you check you have included mage.php currect

Comment: require_once ("/var/www/magento_pack/app/Mage.php");
umask(0);
Mage::app();       if you are using  server then give correct path

Comment: i am getting this array in $core_session object  Mage_Core_Model_Session Object ( [_skipSessionIdFlag:protected] => [_sessionHosts:protected] => Array ( [127.0.1.1] => 1 ) [_data:protected] => Array ( [_session_validator_data] => Array ( [remote_addr] => 127.0.0.1 [http_via] => [http_x_forwarded_for] => [http_user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0 ) ) [_hasDataChanges:protected] => [_origData:protected] => [_idFieldName:protected] => [_isDeleted:protected] => [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array ( ) [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array ( ) ) .

Comment: there are many example on net please read them carefully                    http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57894/how-to-get-session-customer-id-outside-magento                                                               https://bharatchodvadiya.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/get-customer-data-which-is-login-in-magento-for-external-fileoutside-app-folder/                                                           http://www.srijan.net/blog/authenticating-customer-outside-magento/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103713/discussion-between-my-dream-and-shakir-khan).